# How to include Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel in Sencha ExtJS v6?

Tags: extjs

While executing `sencha app watch` We are getting the following exception:

> [ERR] Failed to resolve dependency Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel for file myapp.vie
>   w.staticData.StaticDataGrid
>   [ERR]
>   [ERR] BUILD FAILED
>   [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Unknown definition for dependency : Ext.
>   ux.LiveSearchGridPanel
>   [ERR]   at sun.reflect.Native
>   [ERR] MethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

We have tried to hardcode the path where this extension is located via the paths attribute in Application configuration as is suggested in the following stack overflow answers: [How do you include a UX class in the MVC pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308018/how-do-you-include-a-ux-class-in-the-mvc-pattern) but nothing worked. Perhaps we have misunderstood how to configure the path in the loader as it is not something we have needed in the past.

*Note: we are using the latest Sencha Cmd version v6.0.2.14 and the latest ExtJS v6.0.1*

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: This error persists even if you create a brand new project and you replace `extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',` with `extend: "Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel",` in the sample code. It does not seem to work out of the box

Comment: Cuz you haven't told Cmd to look in the `ux` package like I stated in my answer. The classes have moved, that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Ext.ux` namespace is being moved from the `examples/ux/` directory in Ext JS 4.x to the `ux` package in Ext JS 6.x. Therefore, in your `app.json` you need to require the `ux` package so that Cmd will include it, you'll need to use `sencha app watch`, `sencha app refresh` or `sencha app build` to regenerate the bootstrap data that hold information like file location for classes. Then you should be able to require/extend `Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel`.

Inside **app.json** you should change this:

```
"requires": [
  "font-awesome"
],
```

into this:

```
"requires": [
  "font-awesome",
  "ux"
],
```

Comment: Thanks. A simple TODO inside app.json could do the trick for future users. Alternatively Sencha Cmd could ask the user to configure the packages upon generation of a new app. Let me know if I can help more than that.

Comment: how to use ux in extjs422?

Answer (score -1):

According to this [link](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel) this class is for ExtJS 4.2.2 and therefore is not supported in your ExtJS version.

Comment: Not true: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel

Comment: If you down voted me, thanks for the -1 point even though I was correct in correcting you. Next time, check the docs to see if the class is there, cheers!

Comment: I did not down vote you ;-) And I did not find that class in docs. However I can see it now so I dont know where was problem, maybe typo.