# How to add local filtering option in basic grid using Ext Js 4.2?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have developed a basic grid using Ext Js 4.2. Here's the output..

[image]

Now i wanna add filtering option to the columns in this grid. For example (=, >, <) filtering have to occur.

I have found some source code like  which might work but i am struggling where to add those javascript files. Here's my code:

```js
Ext.define("UserListDemo.view.user.UserGrid", {
    extend: "Ext.grid.Panel",
    alias: "widget.userGrid",
    autoHeight:true,
    style: 'margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 15px;margin-right: 20px;',
    title: '<span style="color: #525252;">User List</span>',
    store: 'UserStore',
    name: 'userGrid',
    id: 'userGrid',
    loadMask: true,
    syncRowHeight: true,
    columns:[
    {
        text: 'ID',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'id',
        locked: true,
        width: 120
    },
    {
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        locked: true,
        width: 350
    },
    {
        text: 'Address',
        dataIndex: 'address',
        width: 450
    },
    {
        text: 'Contact',
        dataIndex: 'contact',
        width: 250
    },
    {
        text: 'Telephone',
        dataIndex: 'telephone',
        width: 200
    }
    
]
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User List</title>
        <link href="http://10.11.201.93:81/grid/ext-4.2.1/ext-4.2.1.883/resources/css/ext-all.css" 
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://10.11.201.93:81/grid/ext-4.2.1/ext-4.2.1.883/ext-all-debug.js"></script> 
        <script src="EXTJS_Files/ListApp.js"></script>
  
  
  
  
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could someone help me with the source code of filtering and how to integrate it with my basic grid as well ?

Comment: Here is example with also source code http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html

Comment: yes. I also noticed that... but how could I integrate the grid-filter-local.js file with my existing grid? For example second line in the source code -- 'Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../ux');'  But I have no Ext.ux directory in my project?

Comment: Here is a question on how to handel the ux namespace http://stackoverflow.com/q/10308018/1732133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have been able to add filtering option into my basic grid. I am sharing the whole process in brief.

Firstly,we should keep in mind that ExtJs is a **MVC(MVCS more precisely)** kind of framework. So, any kind of feature (grid filtering, chart etc) we have to add we should follow the MVC architecture first. SO, I have to replace the **`local-filter.js`** file to the previous **UserModel** .

Here's is the Model View Controller ( and Store) architecture for ExtJs. I am sharing my whole project's directory.

[image]

So, in fine, I place the source code of **local-filter.js** in **UserModel.js** replacing the previous source code.

Secondly, You have to just include **ListApp.js** in the index.php. Then it will implicitly call all the MVC javascript files it needs. Just like that:-

```
  <script src="EXTJS_Files/ListApp.js"></script>
```

Finally, any json file in the data folder will show the data in the grid which will be shown as the way you filter the date. In this case `grid-filter.json` has been used. And, you have to set the directory of data in UserMdel.js like that.

[image]

So, following these steps and kind of grid with filtering, charts could be developed using ExtJs.